# How can I add users into a wso2 Identity server tenant via Rest APIs?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzHDF.png)I am trying to add users into a tenant using this url https://localhost:9443/t/{tenant-domain}/api/server/v1
But it responds with 200 OK status but no user is getting added into actual server if SSL verification is turned off. I am getting this error after turning SSL verification on.

Answer (score 2):

Use the SCIM 2.0 API in the WSO2 IS [server](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/createUser)

Here is a sample curl command:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:9443/t/{tenant-name}/scim2/Users/' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <base64encode({tenantadmin_username}:{tenantadmin_password})>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "userName": "john",
    "password": "Wso2@123",
    "name": {
        "givenName": "John",
        "familyName" : "Smith"
    }
}'
```

Need to change paramtered places `{tenant-name}` and `<base64encode({tenantadmin_username}:{tenantadmin_password})>` based on the your tenant's details.